# Linq select peroperty from nestes list

Tags: c#, linq

Thats my code:

```
class Controller {
    public List<Action> Actions {get; set;}
}

class Action {
    public int Id {get; set;
    public bool IsSelected {get; set;}
}

List<Controller> controllers = GetControllers();

var toAdd = viewModel.PermissionControllers
    .Where(x => x.Actions != null)
    .Where(x => x.Actions.Where(z => z.IsSelected)) // i Am having problem there
    .ToList();
```

I want to get `IEnumerable<int>` of action's with `IsSelected` set on `true`. Without linq it would be:

```
var ints = new List<int>();

foreach (var controller in controllers)
{
    if (controller.Actions != null)
    {
        foreach (var action in Actions)
        {
            if (action.IsSelected)
                ints.Add(action.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunelly I am stuck on `where`. Can you help me?

Comment: `.Where(x => (x.Actions != null && x.Actions.Where(z => z.IsSelected)))`??

Answer (score 6):

```
.Where(x => x.Actions.Where(z => z.IsSelected)) // i Am having problem there
```

You have the problem that `Where` needs a `bool` to determine if this should be included but you provide another `Where` which yields actions and not a single `bool`. Maybe you want:

```
List<int> actionIdList = viewModel.PermissionControllers
    .Where(x => x.Actions != null)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Actions.Where(a => a.IsSelected).Select(a => a.Id)) 
    .ToList();
```

If duplicates are possible and you don't want them, use `Distinct` after the `SelectMany`.

Comment: As an aside, if you set the `Actions` property to a default empty list (`public List<Action> Actions { get; set; } = new List<Action>();`, then you save yourself from having to write null checking logic every step of the way. Nulls are technically still possible (when you manually set it to null), but they aren't _expected_ anymore (you could take this further and always used a field+property so the property always returns an empty list even if the field is null, but that requires more code)

Comment: @Flater: or instead of relying on such implementation details you can use the `Where`. Maybe the Controller class cannot even be changed. But i also prefer an empty list over a null-check if possible. OP used that code so i didn't want to change it.

Comment: The comment was more intended at OP than you :) In hindsight, I should've added "@OP" but I initially decided not to since it doesn't actually alert OP.